# How to keep the added text to the checkbox value in the textarea in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text Area and a few checkboxes. Whenever I select the checkbox it goes to the text area, but when I add some string data to the value of checkbox manually and uncheck or check the same or other checkboxes, the added string data is gone.

For example, lets say i have CB1, CB2, CB3, CB4 as checkboxes.
I checked CB1, CB2 and CB4.
So, the value at current point of time in textarea is:

```
CB1
CB2
CB4
```

Now, i added some data as:

```
CB1Apple Mango
CB2Orange
CB4
```

Now, if i check the checkbox CB3,
Then actual result is:

```
CB1
CB2
CB3
CB4
```

But Expected result is:

```
CB1Apple Mango 
CB2Orange 
CB3
CB4
```

Suppose if i uncheck CB4 now:
Then actual result is:

```
CB1
CB2
CB3
```

But Expected result is:

```
CB1Apple Mango 
CB2Orange 
CB3
```

Suppose if i uncheck CB2 now:
Then actual result is:

```
CB1

CB3
```

But Expected result is:
    CB1Apple Mango
    CB3

Code which i tried is:

```js
$("#input_one :checkbox").change(function() {   
          var text = $("#input_one :checked").map(function() {
          return this.value;
          }).get().join("\n");
         //console.log("text : " + text);
       $(".areaText").val(text);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input_one">
          <textarea rows="8" maxlength="500" class="areaText" ></textarea>  
          <input type="checkbox"  value="CB1">CB1
          <input type="checkbox"  value="CB2">CB2
          <input type="checkbox"  value="CB3">CB3
          <input type="checkbox"  value="CB4">CB4
    </div>
```

Comment: you have over write textarea text in each checkbox checked or unchecked `$(".areaText").val(text);`

Comment: @Omi Can you help me with the code. I am unable to get you.

Comment: @NikantChaudhary Where does the `Apple Mango Orange` came from?

Comment: @AswinKumar That's a manual entry into textArea through a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to try this

```
      $("#input_one :checkbox").change(function() {
    let textAreaVal=$(".areaText").val();
    if($(this).prop("checked")==true){
      if(!textAreaVal.includes($(this).val())){
        textAreaVal += $(this).val()+"\n";
      }
    }
    else{
       if(textAreaVal.includes($(this).val())){
        textAreaVal = textAreaVal.replace($(this).val(),"");
      }
    }

   $(".areaText").val(textAreaVal);
});
```

[Codpen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqMgRq?editors=1011)

Comment: If i add some data as:

CB1Apple Mango
CB2Orange
CB4       and if i uncheck CB2, then it should be :                                          
CB1Apple Mango
CB4    in your case it is:                                                                                 
CB1Apple Mango
Orange
CB4.

Comment: @NikantChaudhary, I don't think so; You can modify according to your requirement; Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation derives the textarea state from the 4 checkboxes' values. You have a listener on each checkbox and when they are "changed", you reset the textarea content to whatever the "checked" checkboxes' current values concatenated with a newline as separator. This is why the changes in textarea are overwritten.

If you wish to bind the textarea to change the checkbox values you could do something like:

```
$('textarea').on('input', function () {
  var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  var currentContentPartitioned = this.value.split('\n');

  currentContentPartitioned.map(function (p, i) {
    checkboxes.eq(i).val(p);
  });
});
```